# Error when removing action bar in theme.material

Tags: java, android-studio, android-actionbar, themes, runtimeexception

I am new to developing mobile apps and I am using android studio. I tried to remove the action bar but every time I tried to change the theme to NoActionBar, the following error appear.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ruleteacher/com.example.ruleteacher.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ruleteacher.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:38)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have tried using `getSupportActionBar().hide();` and it did remove the action bar but there is still this blank space allocated for the action bar. Help me remove this space thank you.
Theme XML file

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.RULETeacher" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

android manifest file
`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.RULETeacher">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity3"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

`

Comment: If you get that NPE when using `NoActionBar` that probably means there really is no action bar. In that case you shouldn't try to call any methods on it.

Comment: but getSupportactionbar did remove the action bar just it leaves space behind. Or am I wrong it is not called action bar? That thing is on the very top of my application. Usually, tell the title of UI. I think there are no apps using it nowadays cause I don't see it anywhere

Comment: I'm not an android developer so I can't tell you what it is called but if `getSupportActionBar().hide();` leaves blank space that might indicate that action bar just not visible but the space is still reserved. If you really don't want that bar I'd remove it instead of just hiding it, i.e. `NoActionBar` sounds like the way to go.

Comment: remove this line `getSupportActionBar().hide();` from your `LoginActivity.java`

Comment: @M DEV If i remove 'getSupportActionBar().hide();'  the action bar or whatever it called appear back and @Thomas if i use NoActionBar in the theme, it will produce the error as mentioned

Comment: As I stated, you should not call anything on the action bar if you're using `NoActionBar`. Your stacktrace indicates LoginActivity.java line 38 tries to call `hide()` which fails because there is no action bar (i.e. it is `null`).

Comment: @Thomas I already remove the getSupportActionBar().hide and then change it to NoActionBar and it return new error which when I googled it bring me back to getSupportActionBar().hide(). Here the new error :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Well, that's the same thing: don't try to call `setTitle()` on a non-existant action bar.

Comment: @Thomas OMG it works. Thank you very much ur a great person for being patient with me to solve my problem. Apparently, I'm using that start-up bot nav toolbar or whatever you called from the android studio, and at that one part, it called the support action bar which I never needed anyway. That is one part I never delete in my previous trial of this method. Again thank you very much, Thomas. May your life always be happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<style name="Theme.RULETeacher" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

instead of

```
<style name="Theme.RULETeacher" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

and remove this from code

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Dont put any action bar related methods

Comment: Not working, I get the same error. I believe I have tried this method on all of Theme.materialcomponent options for noActionbar but it is the same error.

Comment: Sorry not same error but a new error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: ActionBar.setTitle() is an action bar related method. remove this method. if you want title in  your design without action bar, you can create a layout and put textview on top of xml design